# Expanding JavaScript `require` statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollup

In a folder, I have the following JavaScript file `main.js`:

```
const o = require("./other.js");
console.log(o.f());
```

and the following JavaScript file `other.js`:

```
function f() { return 1.23; }
exports.f = f;
```

I need to have an equivalent file with no dependencies on other files, like the following JavaScript file `bundle.js`:

```
function f() { return 1.23; }
console.log(f());
```

How can I do that?

I tried to use the Rollup Nodejs extension, with this command:

```
rollup main.js -o bundle.js -f cjs
```

Though, the `require` statement remained in the `bundle.js` file, and if I remove the `other.js`, it is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct - what you're looking for is a bundler. Rollup, however, will require specific configuration to work with your use-case; it doesn't support CommonJS imports (`require`) by default and will, as you've seen, leave them as-is.

If you'd like to use Rollup, you can resolve this by creating a configuration file that will look something like this:

```js
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  input: 'main.js',
  output: {
    dir: 'output',
    format: 'cjs'
  },
  plugins: [commonjs()]
};
```

and passing it to `rollup --config bla.js`.

You could also use a different bundler, such as esbuild; running `npx esbuild main.js --bundle --outfile=out.js` will do exactly what you're looking for. There are various advantages and disadvantages to using both - esbuild is extremely fast but is considered less mature than other bundlers.